# How to make INDEX and MATCH work with text in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, indexing, match

I have the following code:

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Table1[Id Company],MATCH(1,(D$5=Table1[Client])*(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "=Table1[Id Client]),0))"`

It works fine when using numbers as query data. But when using string, it doesn't find any results.

How to make it work?

Comment: What are the values in the cells being referenced?   Perhaps breaking execution at that line and checking out the values will give you some insight.  See [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: There are many differents values like: "Green Version", "TEEN 14", "8144". But without quotes. I thank you, but the Domenic answer was enough to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text values, you'll need to add quotes around the criteria for the second condition in MATCH...

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Table1[Id Company],MATCH(1,(D$5=Table1[Client])*(""" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & """=Table1[Id Client]),0))"
```